# Bad request 400 from custom ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

I tried everything I think but still getting bad request 400 Ajax WordPress. I have try applying serialize and answers found in other thread but still getting 400 bad error.

**Custom Page Template index.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myblog_ajax_enqueue' );
function myblog_ajax_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_script('myblog-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/templates/blog/js/ajax.js',array('jquery'));
  wp_localize_script(   'myblog-ajax-script','myblog_ajax_obj', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')));
}
```

**blogcontent.php**

```
function myblog_ajax_request() {
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myblog-ajax-script' ) ) {
        die( 'Nonce value cannot be verified.' );
    }
    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];
        // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }
        echo $fruit;
    }
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_myblog_ajax_request', 'myblog_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myblog_ajax_request', 'myblog_ajax_request' );
```

**Ajax.Js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  var fruit = 'Banana';

  // This does the ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url: myblog_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'action': 'myblog_ajax_request',
      'fruit': fruit,
      'nonce': myblog_ajax_obj.nonce
    }),
    success: function(data) {
      // This outputs the result of the ajax request
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    dateType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  });

});
```

Comment: You’re sending the data as JSON: `JSON.stringify`. This won’t work because `$_POST['action']` won’t be populated. See the example from the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#client-side-summary

Comment: I have also tried that, you can see the original code here https://gist.github.com/devinsays/69a305053e35a10584f94d6011bba2d6 but still getting 400 bad error

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API to handle AJAX instead? It gives human readable error messages rather than a HTTP code and `0`, has pretty URLs, it'll even handle authentication checking for you with a few extra parameters

Answer (score 3):

There's only one reason you get a 400 error with admin-ajax.php: The `wp_ajax_{$action}` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` action has not been hooked with an `{$action}` that matches the `action` data parameter sent with your request. So either your callback is not hooked, or you're not sending the action correctly. Your code is making both errors.

1. You are encoding the data sent to the server as JSON. WordPress looks for `$_REQUEST['action']` to trigger the appropriate action. When data is sent to the server as JSON, `$_REQUEST` cannot be populated, so `$_REQUEST['action']` does not exist, meaning that your callback is never run. You need to remove `JSON.stringify()` from your code.
2. You are running `add_action()` for `wp_ajax_myblog_ajax_request` inside a page template. This won't work. You are sending your request to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, but that code does not load templates, so your callback is not hooked for that request. You need to use `add_action()` inside a file that *is* loaded inside `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, such as your theme's functions.php file, or a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

> blogcontent.php

When WP is contacted to handle the Admin AJAX request, it doesn't load a page template. Remember, every request to WP loads WP from a blank slate. It doesn't know anything about the previous requests, only what it's told.

So because you aren't requesting that page, the template never loads, the filters never run, so there is no AJAX handler to take your request.

So instead, move your filters to `functions.php`. Also consider using the modern REST API to handle your requests, it's easier, nicer to debug with human readable error messages, and it'll sanitize authenticate and validate for you if you tell it how! You even get a nice friendly URL.

Once that's been done, undo all the other things you did to try and fix this, like setting the datatype, or contenttype, that's hurting you not helping.

Answer (score 0):

1. Send is as object, not a JSON string
2. Remove content type, you should let is default ( `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)
3. Remove dataType - you send response as text, not a json. ( for JSON response use `wp_send_json` )
4. Ensure that you register you ajax actions in init files ( your plugin main file or functions.php )
5. Also you can try debug it step by step in wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. 400 error means you code get this file, but action isnt recognized

   ```
    url: myblog_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      action: 'myblog_ajax_request',
      fruit: fruit,
      nonce: myblog_ajax_obj.nonce
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
   ```

Comment: that would the original code I have before adding JSON and was getting bad error. Also I am using a custom page template instead of a plugin

Comment: So blogcontent.php is a page template? You can’t hook ajax callbacks inside a template. That code needs to go in functions.php.

Comment: Jacob is right, by the time you're in the template it's too late, it needs to be done in a plugin or `functions.php`

Comment: okay so if I only want to trigger it in a particular page, does it mean I have to use is_page() ?

Comment: @JacobPeattie which code are you referring to? index.php, blogcontent.php or ajax.js?

Comment: I moved the blogcontent.php content to functions.php and the bad request is no longer showing but how will  I pass the value from functions.php to blogcontent.php or data

Comment: That's what the script is for...